# Turning a player's points value into a 1-10 match rating scale?

Tags: normalization, scales, rating

So I have the players "fantasy score" stat. This stat is the sum of their ingame stats multiplied by preset weights. These weights are from the video game DOTA 2's official fantasy points weights. For example:

```
Points for kills are calculated by the number of kills *.3 
Points for deaths are calculated by starting at 3 and subtracting .3 per death
```

There isn't a set minimum nor maximum for what these scores can be. I want to take these scores and normalize them to a 1-10 scale similar to soccers 1-10 match rating system. I don't have a sold statistics background so I don't know where to start. Should I play around with the weights work? Should I look at the standard deviation? Should I look at the distribution and scale it that way?

I know a decent amount of machine learning through python, but I worry that my lack of stats background could negatively influence the scale I would have to create for the training data

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why does normalization help solve that problem?

Comment: I am trying to model the fantasy stats into an cleaner scale of 1-10 to later use in machine learning to predict matches @Sycorax

Comment: Why can't you use the raw scores to make those predictions? What problem does normalization solve?

Comment: @Sycorax I do realize that you are right about using the raw scores for the predictions. But I do still want to normalize them as I feel it will be easier for the user to digest

Comment: You think that users will find it easier to understand a normalization scheme that you invented instead of using the official scores that DOTA2 produces?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the comments indicate that any such scheme is not really needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you’ve clarified in comments that you’re trying to construct intuitive measures, I think it’s worth considering what would be required to construct a bounded scale for unbounded inputs using this data.

You state in the question that the scores are unbounded. So we need a scheme to map real numbers to (0,10). There obviously isn’t any linear map that can do this, so we are left with nonlinear maps.

The inverse logistic function is a candidate. It maps any real number to (0,1), so you just multiply the output by 10 to make a scale from 0 to 10.

But this scale is nonlinear, so it would seem to be harder to understand than the original data, which is constructed by linear functions according to your post. For example, an increase in argument at the high or low end of the scale had a small change in the value. This is what happens when you map unbounded values to a range.

Another scheme would use data about some reference population of players. For example, you could use ranking. To rescale to your context, this is a player’s ECDF in some variable multiplied by 10. This has an obvious interpretation — how am I doing relative to all other players? — but this is also a crude measure. From your post, it looks like most of these values are integers, so lots of players will have the same rank, which isn’t enormously informative. Moreover, exactly the same complications arise here that arose when using the inverse logistic function, since you’re still trying to map unbounded values to (0,10).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to determine the distribution of the Dota 2 scores. Once you know the distribution you can use the quantile function for the distribution to see where the values lie on a 0 to 1 scale. From that 0 to 1 scale you should be able to convert them to 1 to 10. You can use the scipy package in python to compute quantiles using the ppf portion of distribution. You can also test whether your data set follows a particular distribution using the Anderson Darling test. If your data follows a normal distribution though, you should be able to subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation to obtain the normalized value. You can then plug that value into the quantile function in sci-py to get the quantile.